# remove ALL 3rd party annotations from MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit

I already managed to remove most of the 3rd party annotations on my MKMapView using this command:

```
[map setShowsPointsOfInterest:NO];
```

But there are still many as you can see here:
[image: I want to remove these]

How can I get rid of these, too?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do that WHILE keeping the apple map material.

those building names are part of the map material itself.

Comment: Hmm ok, The problem is for example "San Francisco Bay Computer Services" is like an advertisement. My customer needs a neutral map without any annotations, only street  & city names.

Comment: you can look at Openstreet Map Material or Mapbox or Google Maps